# Automorphism with no fixed points other than identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to prove the following: Let $G$ be a finite group. If $f:G\rightarrow G$ is an automorphism with no fixed points other than the identity, then $G=\{(x^{-1})f(x) \mid x \in G\}$.

Here is what I have:
For all $x, y \in G$, $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$ because $f$ is injective. Also for all $x, y \in G$, $x^{-1} = y^{-1}$ implies $x=y$ because inverses are unique.

Therefore $x^{-1}f(x) = y^{-1}f(y)$ implies $x=y$. Define a map $\phi: G \rightarrow G$ as $\phi(x) = xf(x)$, then $\phi$ is injective (shown above). But $G$ is finite, so $\phi$ is surjective. Hence $\phi$ is a bijective map. So for all $g \in G$, $g=x^{-1}f(x)$ for some $x \in G$. Hence $G \subseteq \{(x^{-1})f(x) \mid x \in G\}$.

Is my proof correct?

edit: Okay I know there are flaws in my proof because I didn't use the fact that $f$ does not fix any non-identity element. But what did I do wrong?

Comment: why $x^{-1}f(x) = y^{-1}f(y)$ implies $x=y$?

Comment: From the injectivity of mappings $x\mapsto f(x)$ and $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ you cannot directly conclude injectivity of $x\mapsto x^{-1}f(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't justified the following:

> Therefore $x^{-1}f(x) = y^{-1}f(y)$ implies $x=y$.

Of course it isn't true that $ab=cd$ implies $a=c$ or $c=d$.

A proper explanation would be that $x^{-1}f(x) = y^{-1}f(y)$ implies 
$$ f(x y^{-1})= x \cdot x^{-1}f(x) \cdot f(y)^{-1} = x \cdot y^{-1}f(y) \cdot f(y)^{-1} = x y^{-1} $$
an hence $xy^{-1} = 1$ by the assumption on $f$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $x^{-1}f(x)=y^{-1}f(y)$ then $yx^{-1}=f(y)f(x)^{-1}=f(yx^{-1})$

Comment: But then I'm not using the fact that $f$ is bijective? Or is that irrelevant?

Comment: It's enough for $f:G\to G$ to be an endomorphism that has only one fixed point. Then it can be shown that $x\mapsto x^{-1}f(x)$ is injective (hence surjective since $G$ is finite).