# If $\phi : G \to G$ is a Lie group automorphism without fixed points, is $g^{-1}\phi(g)$ surjective?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

> If $G$ is a real connected Lie group and $\phi : G \to G$ is a Lie group automorphism without fixed points other than $e$, does it follow that the map $\psi : g \mapsto g^{-1} \phi(g)$ surjective? Can we describe its inverse?

Note that that $\psi$ is injective. ([Automorphism with no fixed points other than identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236632)) The example $G = \mathbb Z$ and $\phi(n) = -n$ shows that we need $G$ connected.

**Context:** I was reading a computation in Iwaniec's *Spectral Methods of Automorphic Forms*, where the case of $G = N = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & * \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \right\} \subset \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ and $\phi = \mathrm{Ad}_a$ with $a = \begin{pmatrix}y & 0 \\ 0 & y^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$, $y > 1$, occurs in a computation for the Selberg trace formula. The inverse of $\psi$ is easily computed as $\begin{pmatrix}1 & n \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}1 & n/(y^2 - 1) \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, but I want to understand this conceptually.

**Idea:** in the example above we have, by Taylor expansion,
$$
\psi^{-1}(n)
= \prod_{k = 1}^\infty \mathrm{Ad}_{a^{-k}}(n)
$$
Maybe in the general case, $\psi^{-1}(g) = \cdots \phi^{-3}(g) \phi^{-2}(g) \phi^{-1}(g)$ ? Provided the product converges?

Comment: If $G$ is either compact or abelian, this is easy, if it's any help. (I imagine you realized this already).

Comment: Why is it true for compact G?

Comment: Well, I might be wrong, but my reasoning is as follows: The image of $\psi$ is always open (by invariance of domain), and if $G$ is compact it must also be closed. Since $G$ is connected, the image of $\psi$ has to be everything.

Comment: Got it, thanks.